# Appending to a line that has X but does not have Y

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting

Sample Text

```
I like Linux
I like Microsoft
I like Solaris
I hate Linux
I hate Microsoft
I hate Solaris
```

I'm trying to figure out out to append a line that matches regex X but doesn't have regex Y. Using the sample text, I'm trying to get the following.

```
I like Linux
I like Microsoft and Linux
I like Solaris and Linux
I hate Linux
I hate Microsoft
I hate Solaris
```

Note that it only adds to lines that have `like` and does not have `Linux`.

Comment: Also always try adding your efforts too in your post which you have put in order to solve your problem in code tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be simpler with `awk`. `> tmp_file && mv tmp_file Input_file` is for saving the output into Input_file itself, it will create a temp file and change it to actual Input_file itself then), try `gawk -i inplace` option in spite of `awk` shown following in case you have it on your system.

```
awk '/like/ && !/Linux/{$0=$0 " and Linux"} 1'  Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Following is the explanation for above code too.

```
awk '
/like/ && !/Linux/{     ##Checking condition if a line contains string like and DO NOT contain Linux then do following.
  $0=$0 " and Linux"    ##Re-creating $0(current line) with $0 value itself and string " and Linux" here as per OP request.
}                       ##Closing block for this condition now.
1                       ##awk works on method of pattern and action, 1 means making condition/pattern TRUE and NO action mentioned so by default print will happen.
' Input_file          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: I was thinking of sed with -i to write straight to the file. Is there some arg I'm unaware of to write to the input file without blasting it away?

Comment: @BoydAko, please check my update now, you could write into Input_file itseld by running above command, let me know how it goes then?

Comment: Thanks. But I was trying to avoid piping to a new file. But, I guess that's unavoidable.

Comment: `-i` doesn't exist for GNU awk 4.0.2 on Redhat... Fudge sticks.

Comment: @BoydAko, not an issue no, you can use this tmp_file one, it will NOT keep this file after execution of code since it will again rename it to actual Input_file so no issues I believe.

Answer (score 0):

This is done using awk

```
awk '/like/ && !/Linux/ {print $0, "and Linux"}
     !( /like/ && !/Linux/) {print $0}' filename
```